# How to display XML source code using HTML with Emacs?

Tags: html, xml, emacs, escaping, html-entities

In the HTML file, I need to show some XML code. The problem is that I can't use

```
<pre>..</pre>
```

to show '<' and '>'.

What would be the solution for this problem?

### ADDED

From the answer, replacing '<' and '>' to `&lt;` and`&gt;` can be a solution. I'm an Emacs user, are there Emacs tools/magic to do that automatically? I mean, I can use search and replace, but I expect Emacs can do it by 'select region' -> 'M-x replace_xml' or something.

Comment: Why can't you use `<pre>`?  Tell us more about your constraints.

Comment: do you want 'nice' formatting too? Don't mentioned that, just assuming as that makes for great display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape `<` as `&lt;` and `&` as `&amp;`. Optionally, for consistency, you can escape `>` as `&gt;`

To do this automatically in Emacs, if you're in HTML mode, you can select the code that you would like to escape, and run <kbd>M-x sgml-quote</kbd>.

Comment: M-x sgml-quote is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`. How to do this depends on the server side language in question.

---

**Update**: as per your update: this is not programming related anymore. I think http://superuser.com is a better place to ask software related questions.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you need to escape the XML. For robustness I would also escape single and double quotes too. Note that `CDATA` and `<pre>` can cause you problems if, for any reason, your XML document includes `]]>` or `</pre>` in it.

You can get away with doing a straight string substitution for the escaping, but if you do, make sure you escape `&` to `&amp;` before doing any of the other escapes.

Answer (score 0):

As other have noted, you need to escape the xml markup to display it in html.

Take a look at [xmlverbatim](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/) stylesheet: It does that as well as pretty printing and colorizing.

If you google around there are several stylesheets to do similar formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Do a substitution using a programming language without Emacs.

For Python:

```
#Make a copy just in case.
#Open file.
#Read lines.
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace("<pre>", "&lt;").replace("</pre>", "&gt;")
#Output to file.
#Enjoy!
```

Answer (score 0):

- Select the region
- Do <kbd>M-%</kbd> `<` <kbd>RET</kbd> `&lt;` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd>